Problema para cambiar el directorio de base de datos en mariadb
Soy usuario de debian 12. El asunto es que he intentado cambiar el directorio de base de datos desde var/lib/mysql a home/bladimir/BD. Para ello he seguido el siguiente procedimiento: 1. sudo systemctl stop mariadb. 2. Copio la la base de datos al nuevo directorio: sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql/* /home/bladimir/BD, 3. Cambio el propietario del nuevo directorio: chown mysql:mysql /home/bladimir/BD. Modifico el archivo: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf. y agrego las lineas siguientes:
    [mysqld]:
    datadir=/home/bladimir/BD
    socket=/home/bladimir/BD/mysql.sock

    [client]:
    port=3306
    socket=/home/bladimir/BD/mysql.sock

Tambien cambio la linea de datadir y coloco la linea: /home/bladimir/BD. Aqui me llama la atencion que originalmente esta linea esta comentada en este archivo lo cual indica que no es usada por mariadb. Finalmente guardo todo y reincio el sistema.
Al verificar la nueva localizacion del directorio de base de datos con sudo mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@datadir;" me aparece el directorio var/lib/mysql o bien dice que no es posible la conexion. Pienso que debe haber otro directorio en mariadb donde se aloje la base de datos. Alguna idea para corregir el problema se agradece. Saludos a todos.

qué otros archivos de configuración te aparecen en /etc/mysql/?
